# Finding same word in different column on excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

Python noob here. I have an excel fine to work on with various columns, the main problem is to find matching words with matching emotions as you can see in the screenshot here. [image: screenshot here]

The output would be a new file with something just like this.

[image: just like this] I need only the matching emotions from the two marked columns, so this would work just like a filter but only for matching words.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do:

1. Import your data (in 'namefile.xlsx', 'Sheet1') with pandas, transform it into list. Note that the first list is taken as a header:

```
import pandas as pd
excel = pd.read_excel('namefile.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
excel_list = excel.values.tolist()
```

2. Then, as you presented in your screenshot, I would search into the list's elements:

```
for row in excel_list: #  to check in every row

    if 'abbandonato' in row and 'sadness' in row:  # if both elements exist
```

Then you do your action (take the emotion index or whatever). I hope that it helps.